# "Numerological" assistance requested pertaining to the computation of a certain quantum-information-theoretic volume

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, differential-geometry

I've been pursuing some research (https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.09228) based on the publication, "Complementarity Reveals Bound Entanglement of Two Twisted Photons"  https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5046

But, hopefully, this "numerological" question can be considered without having to delve deeply into these papers and the underlying ("magic simplices") subject matter.
(Otherwise, I could post the question to https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com .)

There are two sets of questions at hand, call them A and B, each with two parts (one part of a lower-dimensional, and the other part, a higher-dimensional nature).

The solution (a certain 3-dimensional ["positive-partial-transpose"] volume) to the lower-dimensional part of A is $\frac{8 \pi}{27 \sqrt{3}}$ and to the lower-dimensional part of B (a certain 4-dimensional "PPT" volume) is  $\frac{1}{24} (12+\sqrt{3} \log (2-\sqrt{3}))$.

This pair of results was obtainable through analytic means. However, it appears that numerical methods must be relied upon in the two higher (8 and 15)-dimensional settings.

In fact, an intensive numerical analysis has indicated (to 6-7 decimal places) that for problem A, the higher (8-)dimensional solution is, remarkably elegantly (in light of the $\frac{8 \pi}{27 \sqrt{3}}$ result), $\frac{7 \pi}{25 \sqrt{5}}$.

So, only the higher (15)-dimensional ("equally elegant"?) analogue of $\frac{1}{24} (12+\sqrt{3} \log (2-\sqrt{3}))$ is needed. In fact, I am pursuing a numerical strategy in this case as well. It appears that the solution is (to four decimal places) 0.1157. (I think I should be able to add a digit or two to this in a day or two, when I obtain access to further results.)

So--"modulo" the assumption of high elegance--can one advance a conjecture (presumably containing a log) that would seem to nicely fit these patterns?

Comment: This page on _experimental mathematics_ may point you to tools that can guess or check elegant formulations like yours: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_mathematics#Tools_and_techniques

Comment: Thanks, Ethan! I've made a lot of use of https://www.wolframalpha.com over the last several years, with often interesting guesses being given. But I clearly don't presently have sufficiently high precision for meaningful use of that site. That log formula just "screams" elegance, what with $24 = 4! =2 \cdot 12$ and 2 and 3's. Hard (?) to imagine--that's the problem I posed--an equally elegant counterpart.